# how to add a string property in view for viewserver to dump

Tags: java, android, view-debugging

I'm trying to add a string property in Android View.java and make ViewServer could dump view and get it.

Here is what I wrote, but it doesn't work.

```
protected String mTestinfo = "myTestInfo";
/** {@hide} */
@ViewDebug.ExportedProperty
public String getTestinfo(){
    return mTestinfo;
}
```

Could anyone help on this?

Comment: What is the problem, what does not work?

Comment: I used String, here the 'string' is a typo, sorry. What I want is to set this property and ViewServer could get this when dump a view, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried changing it to:

```
public String getTestinfo(){
    return mTestinfo;
}
```

with a capital 'S'?

Comment: sorry, I use String yes, but it doesn't work, here the 'string' is a typo